# Check if dataframe value +/- 1 exists anywhere else in a given column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
   irrelevant   location
0           1          0
1           2          0
2           3          1
3           4          3
```

How do I create a new true/false column "neighbor" to indicate if the value in "location" +/- 1 (plus or minus 1) exists anywhere else in the "location" column. Such that:

```
   irrelevant   location   neighbor
0           1          0       True
1           2          0       True
2           3          1       True
3           4          3       False
```

The last row would be false, because neither 2 nor 4 appear anywhere in the df.location column.

I've tried these:

```
>>> df['neighbor']=np.where((df.location+1 in df.location.unique())|(df.location-1 in df.x.unique()), True, False)

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

```
>>> df['tmp']=np.where((df.x+1 in df.x.tolist())|(df.x-1 in df.x.tolist()), 'true', 'false')

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Alternatively, thanks in advance for help directing me to earlier instances of this question being asked (I don't seem to have the right vocabulary to find them).

Comment: Does the "neighbor" value need to be in a neighboring row, or can it be anywhere in the column?

Answer (score 3):

To find a neighbor anywhere in the column, create a list of all neighbor values then check `isin`.

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.unique([df.location+1, df.location-1])
#array([-1,  0,  1,  2,  4], dtype=int64)

df['neighbor'] = df['location'].isin(vals)
#   irrelevant  location  neighbor
#0           1         0      True
#1           2         0      True
#2           3         1      True
#3           4         3     False
```

---

Just because, this is also possible with `pd.merge_asof` setting a tolerance to find the neighbors. We assing a value of True, which is brought in the merge if a neighbor exists. Otherwise it's left NaN which we fill with False after the merge.

```
(pd.merge_asof(df, 
               df[['location']].assign(neighbor=True),
               on='location',
               allow_exact_matches=False,  # Don't match with same value
               direction='nearest',        # Either direction
               tolerance=1)                # Within 1, inclusive
   .fillna(False))
```

Comment: Interesting. Your top example asks the question the opposite way of what I was intending, but I think necessarily ends up at the same result(?). I want to know if either of each row's two neighbors shows up anywhere in location. You're asking if location shows up anywhere in the list of neighbors (vals). It works, because neighborship is two-way: If a row has a neighbor somewhere else in the rows, then it is also neighbor to that other row?

Comment: @relizt Yes, logically they are equivalent because it's using Location as the comparison in both. Let `L` refer to the location column. You are asking `L-1 in L or L+1 in L`. But note that I can add a constant to both sides of each comparison and not affect the Boolean-ness (i.e. `L+1 in L` is the same as `L+11 in L+10`, adding 10 to each side). So let's add one to the first comparison and subtract one from the second. They become `L in L+1 or L in L-1` I.e. `L in (L+1 or L-1)` which is what I check.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a little fix:

```
df['neighbor']=np.where(((df['location']+1).isin(df['location'].unique()))|((df['location']-1).isin(df['location'].unique())), True, False)
```